# How do I Link and ACTIONS FRAME to a MOVIE Clip on a diffrent stage AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, action, frame, keyframe

I'm doing a small Program where there are two keyframe Action in the timeline, that greets the user before the program's homescreen loads. The problem is that I need a button on frame 2 that will take the user to the homepage that is on a diffrent stage in the library. The hompage's code  consists in main.as
thank you